# Appending nested tags with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a select list. I want to append a new item in italic to it. Here is how I do it:

```
$('#idSelectList').append($("<option></option>").attr("value", "new").text("Some text"));
```

But how to make it italic? Here is what I tried:

```
$('#idSelectList').append($("<option></option>").append($("<i></i>")).attr("value", "new").text("Some text"));
```

But it's not working.

I want only that element to be italic, not the whole list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **cannot** put an `<i></i>` tag inside the `<option>` tags. Better you can use this:

```
<option style="font-style: italic;"></option>
```

Or using **JavaScript / jQuery**, you can do this way:

```
$('#idSelectList').append($("<option></option>").css("font-style", "italic").attr("value", "new").text("Some text"));
```

Hope it helps!!! :)

Comment: Lemme try and say. Which browser are you using?

Comment: Will check out and send you a fiddle. I am using `Google Chrome 19.0.1084.56 m`.

Comment: Actually, this fiddle works, but on Firefox and IE! http://jsfiddle.net/UZg2S/ And check out this chart for the compatibility: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/style-select-optgroup-options-css/ I guess better you can use a `background-color` to differentiate.

Comment: Something like this would do? http://jsfiddle.net/UZg2S/1/ (At least for Chrome, which doesn't support!)

Comment: But there's nothing in italic!

Comment: Chrome **doesn't** support it! Use background color instead. :)

Answer (score 1):

try doing it with css:

```
$('#idSelectList').css("font-style","italic");
```

Comment: But I want only that element to be italic, not the whole list.